# Facebook comment plugin Angularjs

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-comments

I am facing a strange error while adding the facebook comment plugin in my AngularJS app. 
The simplified structure of the app page is

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body>
<div>
...
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The page with fb comment box is loaded in ng-view. The structure of page that contains fb comment box is as follows

```
<div id="fb-comment-box>
 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mydomain.com/page/{{ page.id }}" data-numposts="5" data-colorsheme="light"></div>
</div>
```

The `page` is angularjs scope variable which comes from controller. When i load this page in browser and do inspect element. It shows the correct page id i.e. data-href is

```
data-href = "http://mydomain.com/page/2"
```

But below the fb comment box, Facebook shows following error

> Warning: http://mydomain.com/page/%7B%7B%20page.id%7D%7D is
>   unreachable.

I can see the angularJS scope variable is not binding. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that the FB functionality kicks in before Angular is able to change the `data-href` attribute.

A directive seems like a good choice here:

You basically need to create the comment-box **after** Angular can provide the correct URL.
Because this involves asynchronous DOM manipulation, you need to use `FB.XFBML.parse()` to let FB process the comment-box once the `data-href` attribute is changed.

The directive:

```
.directive('dynFbCommentBox', function () {
    function createHTML(href, numposts, colorscheme) {
        return '<div class="fb-comments" ' +
                       'data-href="' + href + '" ' +
                       'data-numposts="' + numposts + '" ' +
                       'data-colorsheme="' + colorscheme + '">' +
               '</div>';
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('pageHref', function (newValue) {
                var href        = newValue;
                var numposts    = attrs.numposts    || 5;
                var colorscheme = attrs.colorscheme || 'light';

                elem.html(createHTML(href, numposts, colorscheme));
                FB.XFBML.parse(elem[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="fb-comment-box" dyn-fb-comment-box
        page-href="https://example.com/page/{{page.id}}"
        numposts="5"
        colorscheme="light">
</div>
```

<sub>**NOTE:**

The directive's scope will constantly watch for changes in the `page-href` attribute and update the comment-box. You can change this to suit your needs (e.g. also watch for changes in the other attributes or bind it once and stop watching).</sub>

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/TLLFg/)**.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer. I implemented your code but got the following error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=

Comment: I noticed the error and update the answer a couple of minutes ago. Make sure you copy the updated answer. (Unfortunately, I can't test it with the real FB stuff, so I am just creating a mock object - hopefully it should work just as good with the real object.)

Comment: I added a link to a demo-implementation (using the mock FB which just outputs the HTML).

Comment: Worked perfectly. You deserve the bounty. Thank you so much for your explanation and work. You help me to understand angular directive too. :)

Comment: how to made this string "<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:3000/7/product-1" data-numposts="5" data-colorsheme="light"></div>" change to html in your directive

Comment: @tardjo: Not sure I get the question. It's all in my answer above. In the sample HTML just substitute the attribute values with your desired values.